# How do I include a taxonomy term in exposed combine fields filter?

Tags: views

I am building a view with an exposed combine fields filter that needs to include a taxonomy vocabulary.

I have completed the below steps but the filter does not return any results when a taxonomy term is entered.

1. Added a relationship to the specific taxonomy term field (field_research: Taxonomy Term)
2. Added a new field based on the relationship created for the taxonomy term (field_research: Taxonomy Term) Taxonomy term:Vocabulary with formatter 'Label'. When displaying the new field in the view, terms do not appear - just the vocabulary name.
3. In 'Global: Combine fields filter', selected new field for 'fields to combine for filtering'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to really add the label of the vocabulary you need to add the vocabulary as an additional relationship. Then you add the label field of the vocabulary to your combined filter.

What you have actually done is adding the reference field from the term to the vocabulary to the combined filter. You may choose a formatter showing you the label but the filter only has the value from the reference field which is in database - and this simply is the id of the vocabulary. The combined filter cannot use the formatter result but only the value of the field in database.

Comment: I think this is the answer I need, but I'm confused as to HOW to get this done. I've added the Taxonomy Terms on None relationship, but I can't see how to assign it to the field to use the label instead of the ID for the combined search. Help!

Comment: I found the answer here: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2012-10-10/combine-fields-filter-and-taxonomy#comment-6943886

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:

https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2012-10-10/combine-fields-filter-and-taxonomy#comment-6943886

> Try adding a relationship to the term reference field.
>
> Then add a "Taxonomy term: Name " field using the relationship you
> just created. Set it to hidden if you like. Then include this new
> field in your "Combine fields filter".